# не работает Pfsense как OpenVPN клиент

Tags: openvpn, pfsense

Прислали нам файл подключения к OpenVPN и список сетей для доступа из офиса к специализированным серверам.
Чтобы все по отдельности не поднимали VPN со своих компов решили пустить через Pfsense. Прописали статический роут (хотя встречал мнение что можно просто в правилах fw прописать нужный гейт). Создали клиента OpenVPN, Интерфейс подняли. Не работает :( подскажите куда копать?

Interface (opt5, ovpnc1)
Status up
IPv6 Link Local ef80::10f:12ff:ffd3:555a%ovpnc1
MTU 1500
In/out packets 0/0 (0 B/0 B)
In/out packets (pass) 0/0 (0 B/0 B)
In/out packets (block) 0/0 (0 B/0 B)
In/out errors 0/0 
Collisions 0

May 27 11:52:11 openvpn 87610   MANAGEMENT: Client connected from /var/etc/openvpn/client1/sock
May 27 11:52:11 openvpn 87610   MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state 1'
May 27 11:52:11 openvpn 87610   MANAGEMENT: Client disconnected
May 27 11:55:19 openvpn 87610   NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
May 27 11:55:19 openvpn 87610   Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
May 27 11:55:19 openvpn 87610   Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
May 27 11:55:19 openvpn 87610   TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]"Внешний IP сервера к которому конектимся:1194"
May 27 11:55:19 openvpn 87610   Socket Buffers: R=[42080->42080] S=[57344->57344]
May 27 11:55:19 openvpn 87610   UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET]"наш внешний ip:0"
May 27 11:55:19 openvpn 87610   UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]"Внешний IP сервера к которому конектимся:1194"
May 27 11:56:19 openvpn 87610   [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
May 27 11:56:19 openvpn 87610   SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
May 27 11:56:19 openvpn 87610   Restart pause, 300 second(s)